# mysql : compare two row on same table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have output like as:

```
+-----------+------------+--------------+
| client_id | date       | spends       |
+-----------+------------+--------------+
|        57 | 2014-09-28 | 39576.384391 |
|        57 | 2014-10-05 | 22664.382575 |
+-----------+------------+--------------+
```

I need such row that if previous week spends is null and current week having spend.

Comment: not clear, please add more explanation

Comment: Could you add some sample data including the nulls you're talking about, and a sample result?

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you need?

```
select t.*
from table t
where spend is not null and
      exists (select 1
              from table t2
              where t2.client_id = t.client and
                    t2.spends is null and
                    t2.date = t.date - interval 7 days
             );
```